# Trackbar with a level indicator inside the track?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, trackbar

I was wondering if there is a way to setup a level indicator inside the track of the .NET `TrackBar`?

My usage scenario is this. I need an audio squelch control. So I want to use a `TrackBar` where the user drags between 0 and 100 squelch. But at the same time I want to show the current audio level in the track of the `TrackBar`. So that the user knows where the current audio level is relation to the squelch.

Any suggestions? Is this something were I need to override the paint method of the `TrackBar`? Or is there a free control somewhere I could use?

Comment: As in some additional floating text somewhere?  Or drawn right on the slider?  Or...?

Comment: Ideally it should be painted as a color bar inside the track of the trackbar.

Comment: Derive a new control from `TrackBar` and override `OnPaintBackground`, then draw your colored zone.

Comment: It is a native Windows component, it doesn't support any custom drawing.  Replace instead of trying to enhance.  Plenty of google hits from "custom trackbar control".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will not be as easy as it might seem.  One cannot simply augment the appearance of the `TrackBar` control.  You have to trigger `UserPaint` by adding the following line to the constructor of a class that derives from `TrackBar`:

```
SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
```

This will, however, force you to own *all* of the painting.  Meaning that you will then need to override both `OnPaint` and `OnPaintBackground` and use the methods in `TrackBarRenderer` to paint the entire control.

Having said that, the methods given to you are pretty straightforward, and drawing the control is relatively easy.

Note:  [this Code Project article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17395/Owner-drawn-trackbar-slider) is bound to have lots of good pointers if you decide to pursue full-on custom drawing.  Perhaps could even serve as your replacement control.

There are others.  Just do a Google search for "C# TrackBar custom draw".